# How to interface OPC UA Server from Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, opc, opc-ua

While there are plenty of Delphi OPC-DA Client components (commercial and open source), I can't seem to find Delphi component for OPC UA. In the absence of a Delphi OPC UA solution, should I look into using an OPC-DA to UA gateway?

**EDIT**

Native Delphi will be preferred, if not a DLL. I'm only looking at basic data access of OPC items.

Comment: [this one](http://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/languages-and-tools/delphi) can...

Comment: @whosrdaddy Yes, I saw this, it's very impressive, but I'm looking at native Delphi and something much simpler - only for data access.  For OPC-DA, I'm using opcdelphi which works very well - [link](https://code.google.com/p/opcdelphi/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at QuickOPC: http://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/languages-and-tools/delphi . Disclaimer: This is a self-promotion.

Comment: Do you have java OPC bindings? +1 for disclosing the affiliation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OPC UA Proxy from Matrikon, which allows classic OPC DA clients connect to OPC UA Servers.